# Menu Sprite Navigation

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, css-sprites

this is the mockup for the site I need to code [Mockup](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3229/dcj752ty_jpg.htm)

my menu sprite is not working properly, here you can see it [Website](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html)

Here is the HTML [HTML file](http://pastebin.com/BEaPRJdp)

and here the CSS [CSS file](http://pastebin.com/gGAUnUgm)

Comment: You should post your code here, rather than links pointing the source files

Comment: what @Mr.Alien said but the main problem I see is that you are applying the background image to the whole `ul` element and then on hover of each `li a` you are applying the hover background image when they should be on the *same* element and to make life easier you could combine both background images to make a sprite.

Comment: thank you @martincarlin87. I am not that advanced. Can you give me a solution for that?

Comment: I would try putting the non-hover (original) nav image as a background on each `li a` so that it matches the hover CSS, you might need to adjust background positions and change the styles for the `ul` but it should work and not be too difficult to do. i.e. do the same for non-hover as you are doing for the hover state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the reason of using sprite for this menu, what about css solution?

Comment: I thought it was easier and faster. Can you give me a good & quick solution instead of the menu sprite?

Comment: here's an amazing tool for sprite on this link http://www.spritecow.com and here's another useful css gradient background tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and its cross browser also as well. hope that help